# Order data ascending / decending - with js or db query?

Tags: javascript, ajax, database

I'm generating a large table of data, and I want to be able to sort through the data, by clicking on the column heading to order it ascending / descending (similar to how it's done on Dropbox, see image).

Im pretty new to programming and I wasn't sure of the best way to do this, either

- Order the table rows with javascript on the front end

or

- Query the DB, and reload the table using ajax

[image: dropbox example]

Comment: depends on a few things, do you want the user to order on different parts, or just on one part?

Comment: When you mean different parts do you mean different headings ? if so yes, id like to be able to sort the data in the example above by, Name, Kind, Modified

Comment: yes i ment that, in that way i would choose to make it sortable on the front-end. Kuje @chandresh_cool said there are some pretty nice plug-ins for it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use some cool plug-ins available for it like

[Jquery datatables](http://www.datatables.net/) that provides sorting, paginating, searching etc options.